# Book series in which a school teacher wakes up and discovers he has become a dragon

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons

I remember a series where I think a school teacher wakes up and discovers he is a dragon or has become a dragon. He is inhabiting the body of a member of a family of dragons and they are unaware he has teleported or in some way taken over the consciousness of the dragon. Within that family, the legend of Saint George slaying a dragon is remembered as the fight between Aunt Agnes and the tin man with the pointy stick.

Does this ring any bells?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, when the teacher woke up in the dragon's body, did he also travel back in time to the medieval period, or was he still in the present? If he was still in the present, then were the dragons known to exist in this time period? Or if not, did they disguise themselves somehow?

Comment: The Dragon and the George by Gordon Dickson? https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjEhsL2_9GBAxU8V0EAHXnNC2MQFnoECE4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsfbook.com%2Fthe-dragon-and-the-george.htm&usg=AOvVaw0r_ppjH-y-8-OGeR_H3KZR&opi=89978449

Comment: _"One morning, as Gregor Samsa was waking up from anxious dreams, he discovered that in bed he had been changed into a "_ -- no, that was a different story ...

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by sueelleker,  this is almost certainly [The Dragon and The George](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dragon_and_the_George) by Gordon R Diskson. This was originally a short story, which was expanded to a book. It the started a series called Dragon Knight that went up to 9 books before Gordon died while he was writing the 10th.

[image: The Dragon and the George]

The protagonist of the story, Jim Eckert, holds a doctorate in medieval history and teaches at a Minnesota university. During a psychology experiment in Astral Projection his girlfriend disappears and Jim tries out the apparatus in order to rescue her.

He wakes up in the body of a dragon named Gorbash. Dragons refer to humans as “Georges” in reference to the legend of St. George. Jim must rescue his girlfriend Angela from those who hold her captive. Along the way, Jim meets Sir Brian, a valiant knight; Silvanus Carolinus, the world's most powerful and crotchety wizard; Daffyd Ap Hywel, the world's greatest archer and a proud Welshman; Smrgol, Gorbash's great-uncle; Aragh the fearsome yet practical talking English wolf (called Aargh in the first book, Aragh in subsequent novels); and Secoh, a cowardly miniature dragon.

As I recall the St. George and the Dragon is viewed by the dragons in a different light, more along the lings of St. Dragon and the George. It was more of a folk tale handed down than the dragons recalling an actual relative fighting him.

The books in the series are:

- The Dragon and the George (1976)
- The Dragon Knight (1990)
- The Dragon on the Border (1992)
- The Dragon at War (1992)
- The Dragon,the Earl, and the Troll (1994)
- The Dragon and the Djinn (1995)
- The Dragon and the Gnarly King (1997)
- The Dragon in Lyonesse (1998)
- The Dragon and the Fair Maid of Kent (2000)